# How can I break up a long EntityFramework 5 scaffold statement

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a very long scaffold command (database first). I use the -force parameter at the end to overwrite the existing files. I would like to break it up into multiple scaffold commands where each successive command appends entities to the dbcontext rather then rewriting it each time. The command line is long because I explicitly list table names. Is this possible by using the -force parameter in the first command but leave it out in subsequent commands? Will this result in appending to the existing dbcontext?

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools, it can persist your table selection in a json file

Comment: Great. Thanks for tip. I will take a peek